# In hugo theme JuiceBar: how to create an automatic outline side bar based on heading markdown?

Tags: hugo, hugo-content-organization, hugo-theme

I have successfully deployed [my website](https://haokaitseng.github.io/post/20230901%E5%8F%B0%E7%81%A3%E7%94%9F%E5%8C%96%E5%AF%A6%E9%A9%97%E5%AE%A4/) using hugo theme JuiceBar via github. It cost me a week and I am so delighted!
My problem is: in JuiceBar developer’s [demo](https://juicebar-demo.add1.dev/post/markdown_syntax_guide/)page, there is a list of heading on the right side bar, which is built on the heading markdown order in the article.md.

However, even though I applied headings such as #, ##, and ### in my article.md, my website doesn’t show the same sidebar as the developer’s demo site. And in my VS code I can still see my headings are correctly formatted as headings in the outline section on the left, such as:

## Heading 1

### Heading 2

How can I fix it and create an auto-sidebar? Thank you so much!

(BTW, I am also looking for approaches to change the font size in my articles using JuiceBar, is the solution is which css section?)

Kai^^

Even though I applied headings such as # in my article.md, my website doesn’t show the same sidebar as the developer’s demo site. I expected that there should be an automatic outline side bar just like the author's page.

Answer (score 0):

### How can I fix it and create an auto-sidebar?

You probably created a 'page'. Only 'posts' have a TOC in the sidebar: https://github.com/hotjuicew/hugo-JuiceBar/blob/master/layouts/post/single.html